# Why is this returning nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been playing around with arrays, and I don't understand where Nil is coming from and why the `a[4]` isn't being overwritten. Please see my example below.

```
a = Array.new 
a[5] = '5';
a[0, 3] = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd';
a[4] = 'hello'
template = ERB.new "<%= a %>"
puts template.result(binding)
```

Returns me the result

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "hello", nil, "5"]
```

and

```
a = Array.new 
a[4] = '5';
a[0, 3] = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd';
a[4] = 'hello'
template = ERB.new "<%= a %>"
puts template.result(binding)
```

Returns me the result

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "hello", "5"]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It's a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby when you say:

```
a[0, 3] = a, b, c
```

it means that starting from the index 0 start inserting 3 objects into the array. but if you say

```
a[0, 3] = a, b, c, d
```

since they are more than three elements, another element is inserted after the third object, therefore shifting 5 and its preceding nil to the next positions.

actually it's:

```
a[start, length]
```

not

```
a[start, end]
```

Comment: That makes sense. But why is it when I remove the 'd', nil exists at spot four. Why do I need to put "hello" to a[3] to remove the nil?

Comment: Indices start from zero, so when saying 5, it's the 6th index. Try this: a = Array.new; a[4] = '5'; a[0, 3] = 'a', 'b', 'c'; a[3] = 'hello'

Comment: Thanks Pedram. As Joseph pointed out below, I think I was confused by by using [0,3]. I don't think I fully understood how it was working with the code.

Comment: To do `start, end` as you wanted, you can use a range, e.g. `a[0..3]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple.

You are defining an Array which is empty at first. In Ruby, if you are inserting a value into an out-of-bound array it will fill all the other past indexes with nil.

For example, if I do:

```
a = []
a[9] = '10'
puts a
```

The output will be:

```
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "10"]
```

All nine indexes before the one I inserted will be filled with `nil`.  Which is the representation of nothing.

Comment: I think the behavior that needs to be explained is `a[0,3] = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'` since it inserts `d` at index 4 but maintains the old index `4`

Answer (score 2):

The problem (as Pedram explained while I typed this) is that `a[0, 3] = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'` does not replace values from `a[0]` to `a[3]`. It replaces 3 values beginning at `a[0]` (`a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`), but since you are giving it 4 values, it inserts the fourth one as a new element after `a[2]`.

If you want to use a range of indexes, use `a[0..3]`. Or you can use `a[0, 4]`.